# jsp- Unable to update table in MySQL after clicking update button

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I created three different JSP pages and my goal is to select the user I want and edit their details and update the table in db.

First page looks like below:

[image: Screenshot]

The updateuser.jsp:

```
<body>
<%

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmc";
    String username = "root";
    String password = "root";
    Connection conn = null;

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "root");

    String query = "select ausername, ausertype from auser where AUSTATE='Y'";
    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    ResultSet resultset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
%>


    <table align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
        <tr bgcolor="#d9ac26">
            <th>Username </th>
            <th>User Type </th>
            <th>Action </th>


        </tr>
            <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
        <tr>

            <td><%=resultset.getString("ausername")%> </td>
            <td><%=resultset.getString("ausertype")%> </td>

            <td><a href="edit.jsp?name=<%=resultset.getString("ausername") %> "><input type="button" value="Edit"></a></td>





        </tr>
            <% } %>




</body>
```

Then, it will proceed to EDIT page which looks like below:

[image: Edit form]

EDIT.JSP:

```
<%

        String user = request.getParameter("name");


            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");


        Connection con = null;

        Statement stmt = null;
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmc","root","root");
        Statement statement = con.createStatement() ;
        ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select * from AUSER where AUSERNAME='"+user+"'") ;
%>



    <form method="get" action="updatetable.jsp">



        <% while(resultset.next()){ %>
    <% String autype = resultset.getString("ausertype");%>
        Current Username: <input type="text" name="old" value=<%=resultset.getString("AUSERNAME")%> readonly/>
        New Username: <input type="text" name="new" />
        <br><br>
        User Type :<br>

        <% if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("SUPERUSER")) {%>
        <input type ="radio" name="myradio" value="superuser" checked >SUPERUSER<br/>
        <%}else{%>
        <input type ="radio" name="myradio" value="superuser">SUPERUSER<br/>
        <%}%>

        <% if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("BASIC")) {%>
        <input type ="radio" name="myradio" value="basic" checked >BASIC<br/>
        <%}else{%>
        <input type ="radio" name="myradio" value="basic">BASIC<br/>
        <%}%>

        <% if (autype.equalsIgnoreCase("VIEW")) {%>
        <input type ="radio" name="myradio" value="view" checked >VIEW<br/>
        <%}else{%>
        <input type ="radio" name="myradio" value="view">VIEW<br/>
        <%}%>



          <%  }
%>


        </table>

    <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>


</body>
```

User have the option to input a new username(optional) and change their user type.After doing so and clicking update, it should be able to update those changes into the table which has Username column and User type column.

UpdateTable.jsp:

```
<body>

<%

     class UpdateUserDetails extends HttpServlet {




        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            String newname=request.getParameter("new");
            String oldname= request.getParameter("old");
            String myradio= request.getParameter("myradio");






            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                java.sql.Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gmc","root","root");

// constructs SQL statement
                String sql = "UPDATE `AUSER` SET `AUSERNAME`=?,`AUSERTYPE`=? WHERE `AUSERNAME`=?";
                PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(sql);
                statement.setString(1, newname);
                statement.setString(2, myradio);

                statement.setString(3, oldname);


                statement.executeUpdate();
   // sets the message in request scope

                    request.setAttribute("Status", "Updated Succesfully");



            }

            catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

%>




</body>
```

The first two forms works fine, only problem is after clicking update, there's no changes in my table db. Am I doing anything wrong?

I suspect it's something to do with `updatetable.jsp`

Comment: Same yourself a lot of pain and use the MVC paradigm.  This will have all of your java code in servlets and having only the JSP for viewing the data.  This will allow for easier coding and debugging

Comment: @ScaryWombat You mean putting updatetable.jsp in a servlet?

Comment: No, putting ALL of your java code into servlets - the JSP should only be doing JSTL expression language

Comment: Duly noted. Aside from that, why it couldn't update the table?

Comment: Because you should be POSTing your form data , not GETing it.